# Create Report Type to show Account and associated Community Members

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I would like to create a report type that shows my accounts and their community members.  I am not seeing a way to do that.  I feel that I should be able to do this since I see the Community Members related list when I am looking at the Account records.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you look at the User record for the Community member, there should be a link to the related Contact and hence reporting can be done that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the need I had to show accounts with and without their community members by creating a joined report.  The first block contained a report of active users & their related contact records.  The second block contained a report of all accounts.  I grouped the joined report by account.